# Images uploaded to Azure Blob container from Next.js displays a broken image/binary data on Azure

Tags: file-upload, azure-blob-storage, next.js13

I am trying to POST images to Azure from my Next.js application.

I have created an account on Azure, created a container and I am able to upload images, however when I try to view the image on Azure it either displays binary data (if I don't set the content-type) or a broken image symbol (if I set the content-type to 'image/jpeg' - I only try to upload jpeg files for now).
The access level of the container and blobs is set to "Container" so it should be possible to view the images.
When I click on the URL created by Azure (for instance https://wilmaenstrom.blob.core.windows.net/wilmascontainer/example-14), I get this error in the console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.)"

Does anyone have an idea what I need to change to display the images in Azure/browser?

This is how I upload the image from the client:

```
const ImageUploadForm = () => {
const [image, setImage] = useState<any>();

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = () => {
      setImage(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = () => {
      console.log('reader.error', reader.error);
    };
};

const uploadImage = async () => {
try {
const headers = {
'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
};
const response = await fetch('/api/postImage', {
method: 'POST',
body: image,
headers: headers,
});
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log('Image uploaded successfully!');
        } else {
          console.error('Image upload failed.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
      }
};

return (
<>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleSubmit} />
<button onClick={uploadImage}\>Ladda upp bild</button>
</>
);
};
```

This is my postImage api route:

```
import azureStorage from '../../app/lib/azureConnection';

export async function postImage(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
try {
const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body, 'base64');
const fileName = 'example-14';
const imageUrl = await azureStorage.uploadImageToAzureStorage(fileBuffer, fileName, req.headers['content-type']);

    res.status(200).json(imageUrl);

} catch (error) {
console.log('error', error);
}
}
```

This is the azureStorage function:

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

const connectionString = process.env.AZURE_CONNECTION;
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString as string);
const containerName = 'wilmascontainer';

async function uploadImageToAzureStorage(fileBuffer, fileName, headers) {
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(fileName);
const blobHTTPHeaders = { blobContentType: headers };

await blockBlobClient.uploadData(
fileBuffer, {
blobHTTPHeaders,
},
);

return blockBlobClient.url;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your code to upload the **jpeg** image file to Azure Storage and saw the **image file** with the blob **URL** from storage.

**Code**:

**app/lib/azureConnection.js** :

```js
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

const connectionString = process.env.AZURE_CONNECTION;
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
const containerName = process.env.AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME;

async function uploadImageToAzureStorage(fileBuffer, fileName, contentType) {
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(fileName);

  try {
    await blockBlobClient.uploadData(
      fileBuffer,
      {
        blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: contentType },
      }
    );

    return blockBlobClient.url;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

export { uploadImageToAzureStorage };
```

***components/ImageUploadForm.js*** :

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const ImageUploadForm = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = () => {
      setImage(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = () => {
      console.log('reader.error', reader.error);
    };
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    try {
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 
      };

      const response = await fetch('/api/postImage', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: image,
        headers: headers,
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('Image uploaded successfully!');
      } else {
        console.error('Image upload failed.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleSubmit} />
      <button onClick={uploadImage}>Upload Image</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageUploadForm;
```

***pages/api/postImage.js*** :

```js
import * as azureStorage from '../../app/lib/azureConnection';

export default async function postImage(req, res) {
  try {
    const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''), 'base64'); 
    const fileName = 'example-14'; 
    const imageUrl = await azureStorage.uploadImageToAzureStorage(fileBuffer, fileName, req.headers['content-type']);

    res.status(200).json(imageUrl);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Image upload failed' });
  }
}
```

**pages/index.js** :

```js
import ImageUploadForm from '../components/ImageUploadForm';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Image Upload to Azure Blob Storage</h1>
      <ImageUploadForm />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

***.env.local*** :

```js
AZURE_CONNECTION="<connec_string>"
AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME="<container_name>"
```

**Output** :

The above code runs successfully as below:

[image]

I got the below in the browser with the above output **URL**.

[image]

Then, I click on **Choose File** to choose a **jpeg** image file and click on **Upload Image** as below.,

[image]

The **jpeg** image file was uploaded successfully to the storage account container at the Azure portal as below.

[image]

With the **blob URL** also, I saw the **jpeg image blob** in the browser as below.

[image]